# Adding ToolBar to GridLayout

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a `Gridlayout`, and I am adding `Link` objects to the gridlayout. The code for the same:

```
GridLayout gridLayout= new GridLayout(items.size(), false);
gridLayout.marginWidth= 0;
gridLayout.marginHeight= 0;
gridLayout.verticalSpacing= 0;
gridLayout.horizontalSpacing= 0;
fComposite.setLayout(gridLayout);
fComposite.update();
```

`fComposite` is a composite with `Gridlayout`. The output is something like:

[image]

Everything is good uptill here. Problem arises when I try to add a `ToolBar` to this composite. I am adding toolbar like this:

```
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(fComposite, SWT.BORDER| SWT.VERTICAL);
ToolItem toolItem = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
toolItem.setText("<<");
```

When I do this, output is like this. All the `Line` object shifts down and is half cut:

[image]

I guess the problem is that width of toolbar is more than of link object. When I make a new `Shell` and try to emulate the same thing it works fine. I guess the problem is in how the parent of this GridLayout is defined. It's a GridLayout. If it helps, I am working with  trying to modify the `BreadCrumb` of `JavaEditor` of Eclipse IDE. Any help or lead will really help. Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear from this what your actual problem is. Please say what you expected to get. You should probably also show us a [mcve]

Comment: Added the actual problem to make it more clear.

Comment: We still need to see a [mcve]